# PHP does not show error line

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have uncomment display error and error_reporting in php.ini. Both is ON. Whenever I have error in my php script, it only shows the error message but never tell which line and which script is error. When I check my error log it does not display anything. Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: what kind of error it showing?

Comment: SYSTEM WARNING: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array, im using nginx..thats the only warning message I get without showing which line in the script got problem..its hard for me to edit

Comment: if it show which line is the problem..im really sure i can solve it

Comment: @ash I never worked on `nginx` server, so I can't tell why it is not showing the line number. but you can search in your code to find the `array_merge` and debug its parameter.

Comment: Yes brother i did that already, there are lot of files with array_merge, it links with each other. if i only know which file I just need to put (array) in front of that particular code and the problem is solve.

Comment: Can you try **hek2mgl**'s solution?

Comment: yeah i done already, i edit the php.ini and then restart my php, but it still the same

Comment: Don't restart your `php` , restart your `nginx` server.

Answer (score 1):

`error_reporting` does not know the value `On`. It's value is expected to be a bitfield, a combination of the error constants like `E_ERROR`, `E_STRICT`, `E_ALL` ...

Check the [documentation of error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to get a list of supported values and their meanings

Comment: Thank you my friend,Yes my friend, i already check, after edit it, it shows the error but not the line and which script.

Comment: Note that for error logging you need `log_errors=On` in php.ini. Also make sure that the log file is writable by nginx

Comment: Yeah it is ON. I manage to solve the problem by doing test and error for each script. But i really need to find the way for that error to show which line. Thank you for your help hek2mgl and Yogesh.

Comment: Ok. If I have time, I'll prepare a test setup and let you know. Will go sleeping now...